# Counting number of entries when there are no entries

Tags: r

I have a table that keeps track of errors that occur during data collection. When there is no error, the entry in the `Error` column is "None". I'm trying to count the number of entries in the data frame where `Error != 'None'` 
This would work:

```
ErrorCount<-subset(df, Error != 'None')
ErrorCount <- ErrorCount$Error
ErrorCount <- as.data.frame(table(ErrorCount))
ErrorCount <- sum(ErrorCount[,2])
```

Except when there are no errors at all. It can't count the empty table. Any suggestions how I can make this return 0 when there are no results where `Error != 'None'`?

Comment: shouldnt you be trying `subset(df, Error == 'None')`?

Comment: Also, something like `if(nrow(ErrorCount) == 0) ErrorCount <- 0; else ErrorCount <- sum(ErrorCount[,2])` in the last line should work.

Comment: Another alternative: `table(df$Error)['None']` would give `NA` if there's no 'None' in Error column. But I can't get your 4 lines of code to finally call `table` against it where it can be done at first.

Comment: @rawr Actually, I should be using `subset(df, Error != 'None')` but I guess the `!` got deleted by accident. I'm going to edit that in.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular subsetting. I've made a function that creates a random table:

```
set.seed(313)

make_error_table <- function(prob){

data.frame(Data = rnorm(10),
           Error = sample(c("Error", "None"), replace = TRUE, prob = prob))
} 

tab1 <- make_error_table(c(0.5, 0.5))
tab2 <- make_error_table(c(1, 0))

sum(tab1$Error == "None")
[1] 5
sum(tab2$Error == "None")
[1] 0
```